# What is meaning of double backslash(column_name\\(1)) in ms access database where clause?

Tags: ms-access

I have some old code which has syntax like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tb
WHERE (column_name\\(1)) mod 2 = 1
```

Can someone explain the statement `column_name\\(1)` in where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As is*, it is invalid syntax. If it is a string in, say, *C#*, it may result in:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Tb
WHERE (column_name\(1)) mod 2 = 1
```

which can be reduced to:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Tb
WHERE column_name mod 2 = 1

*Test for Erik:*

The trick is, that Mod by itself does the integer rounding.

~~~vba
Public Sub TestMod()

    Dim Value   As Double
    Dim Index   As Integer
    
    For Index = 0 To 15
        Value = Index / 4
        Debug.Print Value, Value \ 1, Value Mod 2, (Value \ 1) Mod 2, Round(Value) Mod 2
    Next
    
End Sub

Output:

~~~vba
 0             0             0             0             0 
 0,25          0             0             0             0 
 0,5           0             0             0             0 
 0,75          1             1             1             1 
 1             1             1             1             1 
 1,25          1             1             1             1 
 1,5           2             0             0             0 
 1,75          2             0             0             0 
 2             2             0             0             0 
 2,25          2             0             0             0 
 2,5           2             0             0             0 
 2,75          3             1             1             1 
 3             3             1             1             1 
 3,25          3             1             1             1 
 3,5           4             0             0             0 
 3,75          4             0             0             0
```

Comment: Can you explain why someone uses this type of syntax.

Comment: I have no idea. Perhaps the surrounding code can give a hint.

Comment: Your reduction is untrue. \ is integer division, and causes rounding. The equivalent code would be  `WHERE ROUND(column_name) mod 2 = 1`, which is longer. Note that, like `ROUND`, integer division by 1 uses bankers' rounding. The only mystery here is the excessive use of parentheses.

Comment: @ErikA: All methods seem to perform the same - see appended test, please.

Comment: @Gustav Ah, sorry, I'm too used to modulo preserving decimals in languages I currently work with

Comment: @ErikA: Ah, that explains. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Nice catch - as noted the \\ is a syntax error - that query likely is not being used.